# Issue with Array in Chart creation

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to create chart by [`Get-CorpChart-LightEdition`](https://ammarhasayen.com/2013/11/25/charts-and-powershell-draw-them-now/) script, which I found very good in chart creation.

I have data in hash table. Now as per requirement of above script I need to pass the value in array.

```
$ModelCount Hash table
$l_array is Array

$l_array = $ModelCount | out-string -stream
```

When I print array `$l_array` it is showing data like this.

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                   
CF-31JLCAXFN                   1                                                                                                                                                                                       
OptiPlex GX620                 1                                                                                                                                                                                       
HP ProDesk 600 G1 SFF          1                                                                                                                                                                                       
Latitude E6430                 2                                                                                                                                                                                       
LIFEBOOK S761                  1                                                                                                                                                                                       
CF-19AHNAXFN                   2                                                                                                                                                                                       
OptiPlex 790                   5                                                                                                                                                                                       
Precision WorkStation T7500    2                                                                                                                                                                                       
Precision T3610                2                                                                                                                                                                                       
Precision T3600                17                                                                                                                                                                                      
Latitude E5530 non-vPro        1                                                                                                                                                                                       
Precision WorkStation T7400    1                                                                                                                                                                                       
Dell Precision M3800           3                                                                                                                                                                                       
OptiPlex XE2                   2                                                                                                                                                                                       
Precision WorkStation T3500    1                                                                                                                                                                                       
VMware Virtual Platform        1                                                                                                                                                                                       
Virtual Machine                8                                                                                                                                                                                       
Venue 11 Pro 7130 vPro         1                                                                                                                                                                                       
CELSIUS R650                   1                                                                                                                                                                                       
Precision T1500                2                                                                                                                                                                                       
HP Compaq Elite 8300 CMT       1                                                                                                                                                                                       
Surface Pro 3                  2                                                                                                                                                                                       
Latitude E6230                 1                                                                                                                                                                                       
Latitude E7240                 1                                                                                                                                                                                       
P5Q DELUXE                     1                                                                                                                                                                                       
Precision M4600                1                                                                                                                                                                                       
OptiPlex XE                    3                                                                                                                                                                                       
Latitude E6320                 1                                                                                                                                                                                       
                               4                                                                                                                                                                                       
CELSIUS W380                   1                                                                                                                                                                                       
OptiPlex 7010                  13
```

Here is the command which i used to generate chart.

```
. "D:\Automation\Get-Corpchart-LightEdition.ps1" -data $l_array -obj_key "Name" -obj_value "Value" -filepath "c:\barchart1.png" -type Bar -title_text "Total devices with model" -chartarea_Xtitle "Count" -chartarea_Ytitle "Models"
```

When I execute the script I am getting error.

> Get-Corpchart-LightEdition.ps1 : Cannot validate argument on parameter
>   'data'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not
>   null or empty and then try the command again.

Any advise what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:**

```
$l_array.GetType()

    IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                    
    -------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                    
    True     True     String[]                                 System.Array
```

Comment: Please invoke `$l_array.GetType()` right before you call the `Get-Corpchart-LightEdition` Script and post the output.

Comment: I have updated the output in the question. It is showing string

Comment: Why do you call `Out-String`?

Comment: And whats the output for `$l_array.Count` ?

Comment: @PetSerAl I searched on google/SO and found this way to convert.

Comment: @jisaak $l_array.Count value is 36.

Comment: Why do you think you need to convert your data to string array?

Comment: @PetSerAl I am not good in array and hash table. I am learning it. So, can't comment about string array. I hope you can explain something. So, i will keep that in my mind for future.

Comment: Try this: `. "D:\Automation\Get-Corpchart-LightEdition.ps1" -data @($ModelCount.GetEnumerator()) -obj_key "Name" -obj_value "Value" ...`.

Comment: It is working fine now. Need some tweaks. So, i am working on them. Till the time please paste that in answer. So, i can accept that and i will appreciate if you write something about it.

Comment: This does not seem much different than your last question where you accepted the same answer here as you did mine in the last question. This should be a dupe of yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is taken from [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445012/issue-with-array-in-chart-creation#comment60504418_36445012):

Get an `Enumerator` of your hashtable and cast it explicit to an array using `@()`:

```
. "D:\Automation\Get-Corpchart-LightEdition.ps1" -data @($ModelCount.GetEnumerator()) -obj_key "Name" -obj_value "Value" -filepath "c:\barchart1.png" -type Bar -title_text "Total devices with model" -chartarea_Xtitle "Count" -chartarea_Ytitle "Models"
```